# x86-64 encoding for MOV instruction, weird case

Tags: encoding, x86-64

I disassemble ( with objdump -d ) this opcode (c7 45 fc 05 00 00 00)  and get this   (mov DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x5). then i try to decode myself and i think it should be (mov DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x5) . Why it is RBP register but not EBP register ? am i missing something ?

Here what i have try:
First i look at the mov opcode for C7 opcode.

C7 /0 iw          |    MOV r/m16,imm16

C7 /0 id          |    MOV r/m32,imm32

REX.W + C7 /0 id  |    MOV r/m64,imm32

so there is no REX.W prefix here, and there also no +rb,+rw,+rd,+ro here. /0 mean ModR/M byte only use r/m register, reg/opcode field can safely ignore here. so 0x45 translate to [EBP]+disp8 (using table2-2. 32-bit addressing forms with the modR/M byte in Volume 2/chapter 2 ). disp8 is 0xfc -> -4. and the rest of the opcode is (05 00 00 00) is imm32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 64 bit mode, the default address size is 64 bit: without the address size override prefix (that's 67h, not REX.W) the 64 bit variants of registers will be used in address calculation. That's nice, you almost always want a 64 bit address calculation in 64 bit mode, if that was not the default then there would be a lot of wasted prefixes. The REX.W prefix does not affect address size but "operation size", `REX.W + C7 ...` is the encoding for `mov QWORD PTR [...], imm32`.

So, when assembling for 64 bit mode, `mov DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x5` would be encoded as `67 c7 45 fc 05 00 00 00`, and when disassembling `c7 45 fc 05 00 00 00` for 64 bit mode it means `mov DWORD PTR [RBP-0x4],0x5`.

An interesting consequence of these defaults is that the shortest forms of `lea` use a 64 bit address but a 32 bit destination, which looks a bit wrong at first.

Comment: thanks a lot @harold ^^, got stuck on this for almost 2 days.